# How to monitor Windows Server process Internet activity?

Tags: windows, traffic

Does anyone know a good tool for Windows Servers that would show breakdown of Internet traffic  by processes and users?

I know there are many Microsoft tools (such as process explorer) but does anyone know if there is a specific tool for monitoring traffic?

I was assigned a new task today to keep an eye on about 5 Windows Servers at my university and  I want to be at the top of my game and make sure I know exactly what the servers are doing.

Comment: Are users logging on to these servers and using them as workstations?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, they are.

Comment: Hello, I edited the question so it's not a recommendation for product, but rather a concrete question for a concrete problem. Please remove the hold. I'd appreciate feedback how to make the question even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft Network Monitor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933741) can  attribute captured traffic to process IDs. If you're just talking about monitoring processes running on the servers then this tool will probably give you some good insight.